# Can I use combination of eigenvectors as a single vector to explain most of variance?

Tags: pca, eigenvalues, weights

I have a problem trying to find a combination (or weighted average) of variables (statistics) that best explains the sample statistics.
A – n x p matrix (n: observations p: variables, here are statistics for each observation)

The steps used are:

1. Use correlation matrix C of A to get eigenvectors $V (V1, V2,\cdots,Vp)$ and eigenvalues $D(D1,D2,\cdots,Dp)$.
2. Then pick up top 3 eigenvalues and eigenvectors $(V1, V2, V3)$ and $(D1,D2,D3)$ which explain 85% of the variance for the example.
   Transform $V1$ to $V1^*$ as: $V1^* = (\frac{v11}{\sum_1^pvp1}, \frac{v21}{\sum_1^pvp1}, \frac{vp1}{\sum_1^pvp1})$
3. Then form a vector using these 3 as: $V*=\frac{D1}{(D1+D2+D3)}\cdot V1^*+\frac{D2}{(D1+D2+D3)}\cdot V2^*+\frac{D3}{(D1+D2+D3)}\cdot V3^*$

So $V^*$ is a $p \times 1$ vector and used as weights for these variables (statistics) assuming this will give the best explanation of the variance.

Please see attached image if the formula is not clear. Thanks[image]

Comment: What's the question? I don't see a question mark anywhere

Comment: At the end of title, maybe?

Comment: Please format the question properly. Use bold or slant style for text to highlight the important point to be visible at one sight.

Answer (score 1):

Problem of finding linear combination of variables that best explains them (= has the largest possible variance) is well known and solution for it is known as Principal Component Analysis (PCA).

It can be shown (by [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), for instance) that eigenvector coresponding to largest eigenvalue gives coeficients of desired linear combination.

So, any other linear combination (including $V^*$, you described) has variance lower or equal to that given by eigenvector coresponding to largest eigenvalue.